# Visual Basic Excel Color Cells on Lost Focus

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I need to make a VBA script in excel which colors 2 cells when the value of one is at least 10% greater or less than the other

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Target.Address = aprx_Lns Then
 If aprx_Lns > aprx2_Lns * 0.1 Then
 aprx_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 aprx2_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 ElseIf aprx_Lns < aprx2_Lns * 0.1 Then
 aprx_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 aprx2_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Target.Address = aprx2_Lns Then
 If aprx_Lns > aprx2_Lns * 0.1 Then
 aprx_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 aprx2_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 ElseIf aprx_Lns < aprx2_Lns * 0.1 Then
 aprx_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 aprx2_Lns.Interior.Color = Hex(FFFF00)
 End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Neither of the cells are changing color to the selected color, even after I made the values make the if statement true.
I know almost nothing about VBA, so any explanations would also be great. Thanks!

Comment: `Worksheet_Change2` is **not** a valid event handler.

Comment: Combine both of your logics in to the `Worksheet_Change` event handler. Do you need help with that?

Comment: I do. I know almost nothing about VBA

Comment: OK. Does the original `Worksheet_Change` event work as you expect?

Comment: No, neither of the events are working.

Comment: OK, can you revise your question (do **not** put this in a comment) to include a description of what's "not working"?

Comment: Also, what are `aprx_Lns` and `aprx2_Lns`? You have not declared or assigned these variables anywhere, so that is probably why the event is not doing anything...

Comment: `aprx_Lns` and `aprx2_Lns` are the cell names.

Comment: I changed incom_Lns to aprx2_Lns for the code here, I just missed one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comments above, let's combine the logic in to a single event handler.

Also, it is good to used named ranges/cells, but you need to refer to them correctly. The name itself is meaningless in VBA unless it is qualified as an explicit range.  Pass the name as a string like `Range("aprx_Lns")`, etc.

**NOTE** that this code will only fire when you change the values of one of these two cells, directly.  This means that if these cells contain formula referencing other cells, and the *other* cells change, the highlighting will not occur.

**REVISED & SIMPLIFIED**

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim aprx_Lns As Range
 Dim aprx_Lns2 As Range
 Dim difference As Double
 Dim diffRatio As Double

 Set aprx_Lns = Range("aprx_Lns")    '## Modify as needed
 Set aprx2_Lns = Range("aprx2_Lns")   '## Modify as needed

 Application.EnableEvents = False
 If Target.Address = aprx_Lns.Address Or Target.Address = aprx2_Lns.Address Then


    difference = Abs(aprx_Lns) / Abs(aprx2_Lns)
    '## compute the absolute difference as a ratio
    diffRatio = Abs(1 - difference)

    If diffRatio >= 0.1 Then
    '### if the cell values differ by +/- 10%, then highlight them
         aprx_Lns.Interior.Color = 65535 'vbYellow
         aprx2_Lns.Interior.Color = 65535 'vbYellow
    Else
    '### otherwise, unhighlight them:
        aprx_Lns.Interior.Color = xlNone
        aprx2_Lns.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It's still not working. I got the rgb color online already and changed it to that, but even with your other suggestions it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This absolutely is working. I can prove it, if you'd like. Now, it may not be doing what you *want*, but it *is* most certainly working.  Please describe what you mean by "It's not working" -- what is not happening that should be happening, or, what is happening that should not be happening, etc.

Comment: The two cells should be changing colors when the values are too large or too small, but they aren't changing color at all, no matter what I set the values to.

Comment: What color are they, currently?

Comment: White, and I have the RGB color value for yellow.

Comment: what is the RGB value that you want to use?

Comment: I have it set as (255, 255, 0), so it for sure shouldn't be white.

Comment: OK let's try revision above. I simplified it and also made it un-highlight the cells when the difference is not large enough.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help and dealing with my ignorance!

Comment: No problem! We were all ignorant, once :)